# Autoreleasing objects created in a thread and passed to another in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

I have a method of an object which creates objects which are then passed to a method of another object in another thread, like this:

```
MyClass* myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[anotherClass performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(method) withObject:myClass waitUntilDone:NO];
```

in method, I immediately retain the object, supposing it will be somehow released by the creator. My question is: how do I make MyClass release that object correctly? Is this the correct way to go?

My solution was to release the object manually in method. I see anyway that the Leak analyzer still recognizes this as a leak and seems it is not what Apple recommends, as the owner has the responsability to release the object.

Can you explain me the correct way to handle this situation? Thanks!

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I forgot an important element: the thread that executes the instruction I reported is not a Cocoa thread. I created it using POSIX threads.

Comment: There's no difference between Cocoa threads and POSIX threads. But make sure you create an autorelease pool at the beginning of the thread.

Comment: I read it is also necessary to create at least one NSThread to be able to use NSAutoreleasePools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but in general:

You shouldn't worry about who and when releases/deallocates the object. Instead, just make sure to retain it when *you* (a single object or method of yours) start needing it and release it when *you* stop needing it (or autorelease it, in which case it will be released on the thread on which you called autorelease).

This is exactly the way the `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` works. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> This method retains the receiver and the arg parameter until after the selector is performed.

It retains them while it needs them for doing it's job.

In short, the mehod that creates the objects and sends them to another thread should be:

```
MyClass* myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init]; // retained, will need it for performSelector
[anotherClass performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(method) withObject:myClass waitUntilDone:NO];
[myClass release]; // no longer needing it.
```

or

```
MyClass* myClass = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease]; // will be released automatically, but guaranteed to be retained until this method returns
[anotherClass performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(method) withObject:myClass waitUntilDone:NO];
```

The way you have it now **is a memory leak**.

The receiving method:

- if it uses the object only internally, doesn't have to retain it, since `performSelector` does "until after it is performed" (the method returns).
- if it needs it later, it should be assigned to a property which retains it.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I needed: performSelectorOnMainThread retains it and releases it when done. This is what I needed because now I can release after the performSelectorOnMainThread as you said, being sure it won't be deallocated while still using it. I hope I understood correctly! Thanks!

Comment: The documentation no longer contains that information about `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`'s memory management. Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to understand because you talk about this object, that object, another object and use meaningless names like *myClass*, *anotherClass* and *method*. It remains unclear which object you intend to release and which one is reported as leaking.

Anyhow, multi-threading doesn't add any special complexity to reference counting. Certainly, your two object *myClass* and *anotherClass* aren't short-lived objects. So if you use autorelease, make sure that the reference counter doesn't go to 0 if all autoreleases have been executed.

It's perfectly okay to release either *myClass* or *anotherClass* or both in *method*.

You don't show a lot of code. But what you show is okay.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I can call classes and methods some other way, but the concept is that I create an object in a method and I pass it using performSelectorOnMainThread. The question is, how do I release that object correctly? If I'm not misunderstanding the other answer, that's what I was missing: performSelectorOnMainThread retains it and releases when done. Thanks!